# How to create product quantity duplicate tab on product detail page in backend in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2.3

I just wanted to display custom tab named with "custom quantity" in admin panel product detail page. please help me how to display using new module in detail.

Comment: In custom tab what you want to show? I mean text field, etc,.....

Comment: Can you please write more description in detail so i can help you

Comment: i want to create onother field for custom quantity. in default quantity or custom quantity both value will be same in  product edit page.

Comment: so i want to create a custom quantity field  or need to copy the value of default quantity in to it for every product.